# Fluent NHibernate automapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I was just wandering if it would be possible to use the Fluent NHibernate to auto map a .Net TcpClient object?

I have a class that has a TcpClient property which I would like to map.

I tried creating a custom class inheriting from TcpClient called tTcpClient and adding an Id Property with a getter/setter; however, it was still looking for the Id field for the base class.

Anyone have any ideas if it is possible, or will I need to create my own xml mapping for the TcpClient?

I was sort of hoping to be able to save the object to easily recreate it on reloading the application and to bind the properties of the TcpClient object to the PropertiesGrid and allowing configuration through that rather easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate does not know how to deal with complex types like TcpClient out of the box. But it lets you provide your own loading and storing code. You can use [IUserType](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx):

```
public class TcpClientMapper : IUserType {

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes {
        get {
            return new[] { 
                           new SqlType(DbType.String), 
                           new SqlType(DbType.Int32) 
                         };
        }
    }

    public Object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String[] names, ...) {

        String address = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        Int32 port = NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(rs, names[1]);

        return new TcpClient(address, port);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) {
        TcpClient tcpClient = value as TcpClient;
        if(tcpClient == null) {
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index + 1);
        } else {
            EndPoint red = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            IPEndPoint endpoint = ((IPEndPoint)red);
            NHibernateUtil.String.Set(cmd, endpoint.Address.ToString(), index);
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.Set(cmd, endpoint.Port, index + 1);
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType {
        get { return typeof(TcpClient); }
    }

    // TODO: implement other methods
}
```

And map it like this in hbm:

```
<property name="_tcpClient" type="MyNamespace.TcpClientMapper, MyAssembly">
    <column name="Address" />  <!-- NullSafeGet/Set index == 0 -->
    <column name="Port" />     <!-- NullSafeGet/Set index == 1 -->
</property>
```

Or use fluent [UserTypeConvention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions):

```
public class TcpClientUserTypeConvention : UserTypeConvention<TcpClientMapper> {
}
```

Comment: I see.  I'll have to implement all the methods for the IUserType then I'd presume in order for it to work?  If so how would you implement the NullSafeSet for this?  The property in my class itself would still remain a regular TcpClient right or would I need to change that to the ClientMapper class?

Comment: Yes, you have to implement all methods, it is not hard, take a look at the link in the answer. Property would still remain a regular TcpClient (which is a bit strange from design standpoint). See last edit for NullSafeSet implementation.

Comment: That looks great, thanks for the help.

Another quick question?  How do you know the order of what is getting sent to the Strings[] array?  I realize your reading the properties but how do you know that the address is at position 0 and the port at position 1 in the array?

The reason I ask is b/c I am trying to implement the same for a serial connection.

Comment: See my last edit, columns are listed in mapping file, the same order is used in IUserType implementation.

Comment: Also one other thing.  After implementing that when I try to save an object with a ConnectionTCP that contains the TcpClient, I get a, {"Failed to convert parameter value from a IPAddress to a Byte[]."} exception.  I looked through the NullSafeSet and it seems to be pulling the right values.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I was talking with regards to the NullSafeGet function call.  How do you know the order the properties are presented to you within the String[] names?

Comment: See last edit. "Failed to convert parameter value from a IPAddress to a Byte[]." + indexes explanation

Comment: Adding mapping like you demonstrated above, listing the columns gives me a "property mapping has wrong number of columns: Connections.ConnectionTCP.Client type: TcpClientMapper when calling BuildSessionFactory.

Comment: Also, I didn't catch the failed to convert parameter value from IPAddress to a Byte[] you mentioned but I'm assuming your fix was the .ToString() call on the endPoint?

Comment: @Nathan. The error is most likely related to the way you implemented IUserType. See last update.

Comment: I see, so on the SqlType I needed to specify the type of each of the "properties" of the TcpClient.  Thanks a ton, this has helped a lot and been very informative.  Now I have the fun task of doing the same for SerialPort.  I'd just need to do the same thing but add the columns for all the serial settings I need to persist to create the serial connection?

Comment: Yes, if you want SerialPort to be mapped like TcpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan,

Have you had a look at this project?

http://automapper.org/

Cheers

Comment: Is this supposed to function like Fluent's automapping or something of that nature?

Comment: I almost down-voted this as being completely off-topic, but then realized that you _could_ actually use auto mapper as part of a solution to this problem.  I'll write up details shortly.

Comment: Start by creating a separate class that has all the data you would like for NHibernate to persist to the database.  Then use AutoMapper (a tool for copying data from one object to another) to move the values from your persisted object onto a TcpClient instance.

Comment: So if I have a ConnectionTCP class that has a TcpClient property I just use the AutoMapper to map the ConnectionTCP class?  How do you get the NHibernate mappings from this?